# How can I return a boolean value with Optional's ifPresentOrElse?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I haven't been in contact with Optional for a while, but I have a question.

How do I convert the if else statement below using Optional? Since ifPresentOrElse doesn't return anything, it seems that it can't return true or false.

Is there any way? Or is it correct to use if else statement as before?

```
// Using if else statement
if (obj != null) {
    // someting to do
    return true;
} else {
    // someting to do
    return false;
}

// Using Optional
Optional.ofNullable(obj)
    .ifPresentOrElse(
            val -> {
                // if obj is not null
                // someting to do
                // return true
            }
            , () -> {
                // if obj is null
                // someting to do
                // return false
            }
    );
```

Comment: Why would you want to convert that `if` to an optional? Just because `Optional` is newer doesn't mean you should be using it everywhere.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It's not for a special reason, but just as I was learning about Optional, I was curious and asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are being *given* an `Optional`, just do

```
return optional.isPresent();
```

Otherwise there's no reason to use `Optional`:

```
return obj != null;
```

If you want side-effects also, you could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Optional<String> present = Optional.ofNullable("Data");
    Optional<String> absent  = Optional.empty();
    
    System.out.printf("Value was %s\n", doSomething(present)? "present" : "absent");
    System.out.printf("Value was %s\n", doSomething(absent)? "present" : "absent");
}
    
public static boolean doSomething(Optional<String> opt)
{
    opt.ifPresentOrElse(
            v -> { System.out.printf("value is '%s'\n",v); }, 
            ()-> { System.out.println("value is absent");  }
    );
    return opt.isPresent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote it down in summary, it seems that the explanation was insufficient in code.

In addition to simply returning true or false, there are additional logic that executes when null and when not null. That's why I tried using Optional. (I'm sorry I wrote the code too summarized.)

Comment: Um... ifPresentOrElse alone can't return true or false, so I have to write a separate method. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: Did you notice the `return` statement.  I don't use `ifPresentOrElse()` to return anything.  You cannot combine both into one statement, this is the shortest code to accomplish what you asked for.

Comment: I know "ifPresentOrElse" returns nothing. In this situation, therefore, it would be better to use "if else" or "isPresent" rather than "ifPresentOrElse".

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to execute some code after nullity check. You could simply do,
`

```
 Optional.ofNullable(obj)
         .map(o -> o.doOnNotNull(o))
         .orElseGet(() -> doOnNull())
```

Edit: If you just want to do nullity check and return `boolean` then you can simply use `Optional.ifPresent()`